# Setting a background in flutter from a list

Tags: list, flutter, background, setstate

I would like to have a page called Theme with grid images, and when I click on an image, to select that image as my background to home page.

This is a list I have:

```dart
List<Theme2> themeitems = [
  Theme2(
    background: 'assets/images/theme/deskWhite.png',
    selected: false,
  ),
  Theme2(
    background: 'assets/images/theme/greenDrop.png',
    selected: false,
  ),
  Theme2(
    background: 'assets/images/theme/leaf.png',
    selected: false,
  ),
],
```

This is a home page where I would like to set a background image:

```dart
child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/theme/sand.png'),
         ////// image: AssetImage(themeitems[idx].background.selected), // I know this is not correct
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(.........
```

So, how could I set background image from one of these list items?

I tried using `themeitems[index].selected = !themeitems[index].selected;` but I am not sure how to use it correctly. If there is a problem like this on the net, please send me a link.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think it's easier to rename your images into something more sequentially, for example: `image1.png`, `image2.png`, `image3.png`,...

You can store it in a `list`, but I think you don't need to do that, as long as you've added your images in your assets folder.

And then, to select the image, inside your code:

```
int index = 0; //this variable is to store your selected index

child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/theme/image$index.png'), //So if the index = 0, so image).png will appear. And, so on.
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column( //YOUR CODE
```